# How to resize column of text to the height of page

Tags: html, css, text, resize

I have a column of text. Every word is separated by

```
<br/>
```

Let's say 5 words:

```
<div>
<p>Duck</p> <br/>
<p>Buck</p> <br/>
<p>Cuck</p> <br/>
<p>Wuck</p> <br/>
<p>Puck</p> <br/>
</div>
```

And I want this column to resize to height of the page. Any ideas?
I'm just starting with programming.

Comment: If you just have words then you can use div instead of 'p' tags and include a class in each div and style it as required.

Comment: But is there any simply way to do it? I have over 300 words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this div is at the body level (or there's nothing else on the page) use CSS to style your p tags to take up 100/x percent of available space where x is the number of paragraphs. You can do this programmatically as follows.

```
<div>
  <p>Duck</p> <br/>
  <p>Buck</p> <br/>
  <p>Cuck</p> <br/>
  <p>Wuck</p> <br/>
  <p>Puck</p> <br/>
</div>

<script>
  var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  var count = pTags.length;
  var percent = 100 / count;
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    pTags[i].style.height = percent + "%";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work :( All I've got is http://i.imgur.com/JvNyn0S.png It doesn't fill full height of a page.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated the answer to style each p instead of the parent div.

Comment: Ok, works. But is there any option to add something to div to achieve this. Maybe with JavaScript? I have 300 words and you know...

Comment: Updated answer to give an example of doing it programatically.

Comment: @unknown2549 Does this satisfy your question?  If so I'd appreciate the "correct" answer nod of approval.

Answer (score 1):

Viewport height will do the work. It is used for sizing things relative to the current viewport. 
1vw = 1% of viewport width 
I used 100vh here to cover the whole viewport.

```html
<div style="height: 100vh">
<p style="height: 20%">Duck</p> <br/>
<p style="height: 20%">Buck</p> <br/>
<p style="height: 20%">Cuck</p> <br/>
<p style="height: 20%">Wuck</p> <br/>
<p style="height: 20%">Puck</p> <br/>
</div>
```

**Alternatively**,You can set the height of

as 100/(no of elements) vh.

```css
.myList p{
  height:20vh; 
}
```

```html
<div class="myList">
    <p>Duck</p> <br/>
    <p>Buck</p> <br/>
    <p>Cuck</p> <br/>
    <p>Wuck</p> <br/>
    <p>Puck</p> <br/>
</div>
```